# how to connect from computers in the same workgroup?

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication

I am doing probes to connect computers in the same workgroup to the SQL Server that is installed in one of them.

To do it, I have two virtual machines, both with Windows XP SP3. In the first one I have SQL Server 2008 R2 and in the second one I have SQL Server Management Studio 2008. I want to can access to the database in the first VM from the Management Studio installed in the second virtual machine.

If I go to see computers in the same workgroup, I can see the two computers, one with the name WinXP1 and the other WinXP2. So the can see one each other.

In the first computer with SQL Server, I disabled the firewall, to eliminate possible sources of problems. In the future I know that it would neccessary to open the port 1433 (the default port).

In the firt machine I also enabled TCP/IP and in all the IPs I set the 1433 port.

In the first manchine, I enabled SQL Browse.

In the second machine, I use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and in the connetion window, in the server name, I can choose one, I go to the network servers and I can see the server WinXP1\SQLExpress, so the second computer can see the first computer.

If I use tcping, I can see that the port 1433 in the ip that is used for the first VM is open.

However, when I try to connect, I get the error 18452, that says that I try to connect from an untrusted domain.

I am not try to connect from a domain, but from a workgroup. Also, I want to use windows authetication, no mixed authentication.

So I would like to know if this is possible.

EDIT: In both computers I have the same user and password, because the second machine is a clone of the first one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is that I was using the same user in both computers, but this user had not password. It is needed that exists the same user in both computers with the same password.